# How to specify argument `centers` for `flexclust::distEuclidean`?

Tags: r, matrix, distance

I want to use `flexclust::distEuclidean`, but I'm not sure how `centers` should be specified. There are no examples given in the documentation at `?distance`.

So I checked the source of this function (which turns out short):

```
function (x, centers) 
{
    if (ncol(x) != ncol(centers)) 
        stop(sQuote("x"), " and ", sQuote("centers"), " must have the same number of columns")
    z <- matrix(0, nrow = nrow(x), ncol = nrow(centers))
    for (k in 1:nrow(centers)) {
        z[, k] <- sqrt(colSums((t(x) - centers[k, ])^2))
    }
    z
}
<environment: namespace:flexclust>
```

If `p` is a number of features in my data and `k` is the number of clusters, should `centers` be a `k x p` matrix, i.e. consecutive centroids should be in rows?

Actually, it has to be like that, as this function first checks if `ncol(x) = ncol(centers)`. But then we have

```
   z[, k] <- sqrt(colSums((t(x) - centers[k, ])^2))
```

How `t(x) - centers[k,]` even works? `t(x)` is a `p x n` matrix and `centers[k, ]` is `1 x p` vector, so dimension don't match...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `t(x)` is a `p x n` matrix and `centers[k, ]` is `1 x p` vector, so dimension don't match...

No, `centers[k, ]` is just a vector without dimension. In `t(x) - centers[k, ]`, the [recycling rule](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#The-recycling-rule) in R will apply.

You will get your expected failure if you do `t(x) - centers[k, ,drop = FALSE]`.

---

A simple example for you to digest:

```
x <- matrix(1:6, nrow = 3)
y <- x
x - y[, 1]  ## yeah!
x - y[, 1, drop = FALSE]  ## oops!
```

Comment: Thanks. I totally forgot that extracting rows from matrix returns a "column vector" by default.